# Insert into DB via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, insert

I have created this class which is created in my postgresql db:

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="test")
    private Integer test;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="test_String")
    private String testString;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="test_1")
    private Integer test1;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="space")
    private String space;
```

I want to insert that into the db:

```
    INSERT INTO test (id, type, test, test_String, test_1, space)
VALUES (0, "Type1" , 5, "String", 1, "room");
```

However, I get an exception, even if I manually insert via the postgresql interface:

```
FEHLER:  Spalte »Type1« existiert nicht
LINE 2: VALUES (0, "Type1" , 5, "String", 1, "room");
                   ^
```

Whats wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass string values with singlequotes. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, type, test, test_String, test_1, space)
VALUES (0, 'Type1' , 5, 'String', 1, 'room');
```